# Affect on Spring constant on cutting the spring into 2 unequal parts

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, spring

> Question : A uniform spring with a constant 120 N/m is cut into two pieces, one
>   twice as long as the other. What are the spring constants of the two pieces?

I know that when a spring is cut into 2 or more pieces of equal length, we apply either$$k_{original} = \frac{EA}{L_{orginal}}=\frac{EA}{n .L_{orginal}}$$ (where n is number of pieces of equal length ) 
or 
$$ E = \frac{1}{2}kx^2 $$

to find out what is the new spring constant of each piece of spring. 
However in this question, where one spring is cut in $\frac{2L}{3} $and other in $\frac{1L}{3}$ how shall I find out their spring constants?
What I did was :

$$E = \frac{1}{2}k(\frac{2L}{3})^2$$ and $$E = \frac{1}{2}k(\frac{L}{3})^2 $$
I am stuck because I realize that energy would not be the same in each of the two pieces so they can not be equated with energy of undivided spring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The total energy will be the same, thus: 
$ \frac{1}{2}k L ^2 = \frac{1}{2}k_1(\frac{2L}{3})^2+\frac{1}{2}k_2(\frac{L}{3})^2$,

Also, the force between the two spring segments will be the same ($F_1=F_2$) from which you get:

$k_1\frac{2L}{3}=k_2\frac{L}{3}$

From these two equations you can easily find $k_1$ and $k_1$

Answer (score 0):

In a spring kl is always constant
When you divide it in a ratio 1:3 then spring constant of the springs will be in a ratio 3:1

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).